# how to extract day from date?

Tags: php, database, date, pdo

I do a system that user need to choose a date to check availability. in my database store day of operation day such as Monday, Tuesday, .... Did I need to change the date to day first or else? I do not know how to code in PHP or pdo. If someone can help me to give some example to code it.

to choose date i use datepicker as shows below:
1. javacript

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker,#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

2.html

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="search.php">
<div class="rooms">
<div class="container">     
  <div class="rom-btm">
    <h6>Date:
    <br><input class="date" id="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"  name="fromdate" required=""></h6>
    <br><button type="submit" name="search" class="btn-primary btn">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

3.PHP

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $date=$_GET['day'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbltourpackages WHERE date=:day";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query -> bindParam(':day', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=1;
    if($query->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($results as $result)
    {   
       echo $result; 
    }}} ?>
```

Comment: Please provide some example of your input and desired ouput and also some sample code.

Comment: You need to be much, much more clear. Are you trying to extract the day from a PHP date and insert it into the database? or extract a day from a SQL date and fetch it into PHP? 
... or have you already selected the date from the database, and want to get the day using PHP?
A [mcve] is recommended. 

Please read [ask] for more information about asking good, answerable questions.

Comment: i edited my question do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

What datepicker plugin do you use in the JavaScript? You can get day and date in 2 different inputs, it's easier than separating it in php

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    $string = "2010-11-24";
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $string);
    echo $date->format("d");
```

Comment: the date i need to user input. that code I must declare first right? how about if user want different date?

Comment: $string means  user input. I just added a dummy data.